# Convert PyObject gpumat to C++ GpuMat

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to create a binding using pybind11 in order to transfer directly one python `cv2.cuda_gpumat` to c++ code. Actually I can't find one methodology to convert the `PyObject *` to `cv::cuda::GpuMat`.

```py
torch::Tensor gpumat2torch(PyObject* frame) {
    cv::cuda::GpuMat frame_gpu;
    pyopencv_to(frame, frame_gpu); # <-- NOT FOUND
    at::ScalarType torch_type = get_torch_type(frame_gpu.type());
    auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch_type).device(torch::kCUDA);
    std::vector<int64_t> sizes = {1,
                                  static_cast<int64_t>(frame_gpu.channels()),
                                  static_cast<int64_t>(frame_gpu.rows),
                                  static_cast<int64_t>(frame_gpu.cols)};
    return torch::from_blob(frame_gpu.data, sizes, options);
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(gpumat, m) {
    m.doc() = "gpumat2torch function!";
    m.def("gpumat2torch", &gpumat2torch, "A function to convert GpuMat to CudaTorch");
#ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif
```

I found that there is a method to convert in the OpenCV but seems not public: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d60ac98ef269f06c433450998bd71236f84ef504/modules/core/misc/python/pyopencv_cuda.hpp

Any idea to solve that problem?